# Access item from microsoft graph by relative path to available drives

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to access items from Microsoft Graph using relative path to available drives?

Currently it is possible to use relative path only with users default drive:

e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drive/root:/level1/level2:/children

is working correctly, but using any other drive ignores relative path:

e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{drive-id}/root:/level1/level2:/children

returns items from root drive, ignoring subfolders.